# Representing math in text using HTML

Tags: html, math, character

How would I represent the following using text in HTML?

Are there any special characters that would allow this?

[image: sigma]

Comment: I looked into those options but I do not want to use anything that relies on JavaScript such as TeX. I'm looking for a special character (i.e. &Sigma with an "i")

Comment: @user3216933: you will find the single symbols as HTML entities or as utf-8 characters, but only a few that will act as indexes / subscripts (I know there is an abstract term for these little "i"s...damn...). You will either have to position the indexes with style / CSS, which will become very painful with complexer formulas, or switch to one of the js solutions that do the styling for you

Comment: You won't do better than LaTex.  I'd rethink that and go with MathJAX.

Answer (score 2):

The friendly code looks like this:

```
&Sigma;
```

For the sigma sign.  A quick google search for HTML Encode with give you the character set for pretty much everything in existence.

Edit: Since this was closed before I could post:
Since I think your question was geared toward generating that specific symbol in pure html you can format and generate it as follows.

```
<style type="text/css">  
h2 { 
    color: #000; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    display:inline; 
    line-height: .01 em;  
    font-style: 
    italic; 
    } 
 </style>

<font size="12px">&#x3A3;</font>
</br>
<h2>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspi</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is what I'm looking for, but how would I represent the little "i" as well?

Comment: @user3216933 That might take some fancy formatting or you may need to use the suggestions mentioned in your questions comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use MathML, which is now supported by HTML5, though browser support is uneven.  Take a look at this page for some examples:

http://www.html5freecode.com/MathML%E2%80%93_Summation_and_Production.htm